# How do I specify the order of GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql

How do I ensure, when I GROUP BY QID, that only the most recent row is returned?

```
ID, QID, VALUE, TIMESTAMP
45,1,Male,1362044759
58,1,Female,1362045122
59,1,Male,1362045149
60,1,Female,1362045153
82,1,Female,1362045863
83,1,Female,1362045887
92,1,Male,1362046012
101,1,Female, 1362046401

SELECT ID, QID, VALUE, TIMESTAMP FROM table GROUP BY ID
```

...returns the first row. I can't simply do a LIMIT 1, as this is just an example, there are lots of QIDs in the table, which are all grouped.

Thanks.

Comment: When you're using GROUP BY there's no concept of "the most recent row" - **all** rows are grouped together.

Comment: Yes, but the SQL returns a value, how do I specify which value this is? It's can't be simply random.

Comment: select * from table group by id order by  ID limit 1

Comment: @Arun, I can't do that as this is just an example, the table has lots of QIDs which are all grouped.

Comment: @TheBounder *What SQL?* You haven't posted the query you're using.

Comment: @TheBounder Check the answer, they should provide enough information to what you asked. By the way, next an example of query would be welcome ;)

Comment: @Araknoid...what answer? There's not been an answer which works yet, has there?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming here you want the "latest" row for each `QID`. You would normally use a derived-table subquery to get each `QID`'s latest `TIMESTAMP` value and then join on that:

```
SELECT ...
FROM myTable AS t
INNER JOIN (SELECT QID, MAX(`TIMESTAMP`) AS MaxT FROM myTable GROUP BY QID) l
    ON t.QID = l.QID AND l.maxT = t.`TIMESTAMP`
```

This is also assuming your `TIMESTAMP` column increases as time goes on.

Comment: This seems to just returns the MAX timestamp, and not the most recent value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'GROUP_CONCAT' in order to extract grouped data.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) AS latest_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent record returned:

```
SELECT *
FROM TBL
ORDER BY `TIMESTAMP` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Otherwise, if you want to get the most recent record for each group of QID check this [Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group) that treat your same problem with optimal solutions.